# How to collect a variable length relationship's properties

Tags: neo4j, properties, cypher, graph-traversal

I can obtain the properties from all the relationships that satisfy a simple pattern (length of 1) such as:

```
MATCH ()-[r:RELATIONSHIP]->() RETURN collect(r.id)
```

But cannot obtain the properties of variable length relationships such as:

```
MATCH ()-[r:RELATIONSHIP*]->() RETURN collect(r.id)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

> Error message is: Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Type
>   mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node, Relationship, Point, Duration,
>   Date, Time, LocalTime, LocalDateTime or DateTime but was
>   List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple pattern (fixed length 1) variable  `r` is only **one relationship**, but in the case of variable length patterns, the variable `r` is **a list of relationships**.

Your first query is correct but in the second query, you are trying to get id property from `List` instead of getting it from a particular `relationship`.

You can modify your query to get properties from the list as follows:

```
MATCH ()-[r:RELATED_TO*2]->() 
UNWIND  r as rel
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT id(rel))
```

Above pattern(Binding relationships to a list in a variable length pattern is deprecated) is deprecated and will be removed in future versions.

**The recommended way is to bind the whole path to a variable, then extract the relationships:**

```
MATCH path=()-[:RELATED_TO*2]->()
UNWIND relationships(path) AS  rel
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT id(rel))
```

Comment: Note that if you want the relationship ids per path instead of across all matched paths, you can use list comprehension to extract the id from all the relationships in a variable length path for that particular path: `MATCH path=()-[:RELATED_TO*2]->() RETURN [rel in relationships(path) | id(rel)] as relIds`

Comment: Thanks, @InverseFalcon for a suggestion.